# Free shipping code is not working for UPS in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, ups

If you **create a cart price rule for free shipping**, **it works** on all shipping methods (Flat rate, table rates, ...) **except in the UPS method**. I have tried several configurations but nothing.

I have seen a thread in stackoverflow that is referenced:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936908/free-shipping-code-is-not-working-for-ups-for-magento-2

Although the answer gives solution to mark a UPS shipping method as free ALWAYS. **I need it works only with the coupon**.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found in github.com this bug:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10704